# Trouble importing scrapy into json

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to pull some info off of Craigslist and store it in a JSON file, but the info is getting stored a bit wrong. Instead of having an array of [title, link, location, time], I'm getting an array with all the titles, one with all the links, etc. Are my titles wrong or is the for loop itself wrong?

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
 name = "craig"
 allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
 start_urls = ["https://pittsburgh.craigslist.org/search/ccc"]

 def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.selector.xpath("//p[@class='row']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item["title"] = titles.xpath("//span[@id='titletextonly']").extract()
        item["link"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
        item["location"] = titles.xpath("//small").extract()
        item["time"] = titles.xpath('//time').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your inner xpaths match the elements starting from the root of the tree. Instead, you need to force them to work in the context of each item by prepending a dot:

```
for title in titles:
    item = CraigslistSampleItem()
    item["title"] = title.xpath(".//span[@id='titletextonly']").extract()
    item["link"] = title.xpath("a/@href").extract()
    item["location"] = title.xpath(".//small").extract()
    item["time"] = title.xpath('.//time').extract()
    yield item
```